# How to present outrec data even if there is no data or minimal data given. for PLSQL and Ireport/jrxml

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is the data I have:

TABLEA

```
Name  Branch
AK    01
JN    01
ML    01
```

TABLEB

```
Branch
01
02
03
...
```

However I have n number of branch.
How do I display all the branch in PLSQL outrec if I want it to be like this:

OUTPUT

```
NAME  BRANCH
AK    01
JN    01
ML    01
      02
      03
      ...
      n
```

Here is the code that I have created.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Test
AS
  PROCEDURE test1(inp_str IN VARCHAR2, out_retCode OUT NUMBER, out_rec OUT VARCHAR2);

END test;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test
AS
outArr              tbaadm.basp0099.ArrayType;
    lv_a            VARCHAR(20);
    lv_flag         char(1):='N';

CURSOR cursor1(lv_a VARCHAR2)
IS
SELECT Name, Branch from TABLEA;

PROCEDURE test1(inp_str     IN  VARCHAR2,
                out_retCode  OUT NUMBER,
                out_rec      OUT VARCHAR2)  
AS

lv_Name        TABLEA.NAME%TYPE;
lv_brh         TABLEA.BRANCH%TYPE;

BEGIN
--{
    tbaadm.basp0099.formInputArr (inp_str,outArr);
    out_retCode     := 0;
    out_rec         := null;  
    lv_a:= outArr(0);

IF (NOT cursor1%ISOPEN) THEN
    --{
        OPEN cursor1(lv_a);
    --}
    END IF;

    IF (cursor1%ISOPEN) Then
    --{
        --LOOP       
        FETCH cursor1
        INTO lv_Name, lv_brh

IF (cursor1%NOTFOUND) THEN
  IF(lv_flag='N')THEN 
   lv_Name :='';
   lv_brh :='';

END IF; 
            CLOSE cursor1;
            out_retCode := 1;
            RETURN;
END IF;

out_rec  := 
                            lv_Name  
                            || '|' ||
                            lv_brh
lv_flag:='Y';
        RETURN;
--End of Loop
--}
    END IF;

END test1;
END test;
```

The code will only display the data given in table but not the other branches that have no data therefore is there a way for me to display at least one data from each branch even if there is no data given? or is it possible to do it in SQL?

MANY THANK!!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need a simple outer join:

```
select A.name, B.branch
from tableB B
       left join tableA A
         on a.branch = b.branch
```

For example, this

```
with tableA(name, branch) as (
  select 'AK', '01' from dual union all
  select 'ML', '01' from dual union all
  select 'JN', '01' from dual
),
tableB(branch) as (
  select '01' from dual union all
  select '02' from dual union all
  select '03' from dual union all
  select '04' from dual
)
select A.name, B.branch
from tableB B
       left join tableA A
         on a.branch = b.branch
```

gives:

```
NAME BRANCH
---- ------
AK   01    
ML   01    
JN   01    
     03    
     02    
     04
```

Comment: Hi Aleksej, Unfortunately, I do not know the number of rows I have for both table. This will not be valid.

Comment: I can't understand the point. The first part is a query, the second part is a example. Hod do you see that I need to know the number of rows to use this solution?